# How to store user text input data into an array of inside an object in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a small code to add user input to an array inside objects using react hooks. Below is my code snippet

```
// created the list 
const [inputList,setInputList] = useState([
    {id:'00', type:'', ques:'', options:['']}
]);

// handle change 
const handleChange3 = (e,index) => {
    let  {inputList} = e.target;
    let myVal = inputList[0][e.target.name]

    myVal[0][index] = e.target.value;
    inputList[0][e.target.name] = myVal;
    setInputList({inputList})
  }


//this is the input field
<input type='text' name='options' placeholder='option' 
            className='input-type' value={inputList[0].options[0]} 
            onChange={e => handleChange3(e,i)} 
            />
```

the above code throws error as: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

You are de-structuring the wrong property from event. You will get the value of `input` from `e.target.value`, but you are trying to get it from `e.target.inputList` which will be `undefined` due to which `let myVal = inputList[0][e.target.name]` throws error. You should share the complete code if you are using a `form`, otherwise using `e.target.value` to get the input value should fix this

Comment: thanks a lot. Actually, I am not using form just trying to take input from the input tag as written in the code.